# Django QuerySet filter over string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a models.py file with some rows and I would like to return on my HTML template all rows corresponding to my filter QuerySet.

```
#models.py

def Test(request) :

    CarCollection = MyModel.objects.filter(car="old")

    context = {
        "CarCollection" : CarCollection
    }

    return render(request, 'car.html', context)
```

My html template looks like :

```
<!-- car.html -->

{% block content %} 
<ul>
{% for car in CarCollection %}
  <li>{{ car }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

But my objects looks like :

```
Volvo_old_car
Audi_old_car
Nissan_new_car
old_Bentley
```

So I would like to isolate a string in my object (`old` for example) and return all objects with this string. But this string could be at the beginning, at the middle or at the end.

The filter will return :

```
Volvo_old_car
Audi_old_car
old_bentley
```

I need to use Regex to do that ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
MyModel.objects.filter(car="old")
```

do

```
MyModel.objects.filter(car__icontains="old")
```

This will tell Django to filter out all `MyModel` objects where `car` fields contains `old`.

NB: You can also use `car__contains="old"` directly if you want a case sensitive search.

P.S. You should definitely check the PEP8 Python convention. This will help you to write code that is easy to read for Python developers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know this option !

Answer (score 1):

You can use field lookups provided by Django to filter your queryset.

[Django - Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(car__contains="old")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
endswith or istartswith in query.

```
CarCollection = MyModel.objects.filter(car__istartswith="old")
```